# Is $\mathrm{tr}_\mathbb{R}(A)=2\mathrm{Re}(\mathrm{tr}_\mathbb{C}(A))$? (real trace vs complex trace)

Tags: solution-verification, complex-numbers, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a $d$-dim. $\mathbb{C}$-vector space. $V$ inherits an obvious $\mathbb{R}$-vector space structure by setting
\begin{equation}
\forall (x,v)\in \mathbb R\times V:x\cdot v:=(x\cdot 1)\cdot v
\end{equation}
with $1\in\mathbb C$. Is it correct that
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\mathrm{tr}_\mathbb{R}(A)=2\mathrm{Re}(\mathrm{tr}_\mathbb{C}(A))
\end{equation}
for all $A\in\mathrm{End}_\mathbb{C}(V)$? Here is my attempt:

Let $e_1,\ldots,e_d$ be a complex basis of $V$, then
\begin{equation}
(v_1,\ldots,v_{2d}):=(e_1,\ldots e_d,ie_1,\ldots,ie_d)
\end{equation}
is a real basis of $V$. Hence
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{tr}_\mathbb{R}(A)=\sum_{n=1}^{2d}v^n Av_n=\sum_{n=1}^dv^nAv_{n}+v^{d+n}Av_{d+n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}v^n(Ae_n)+v^{d+n}(iAe_n)
\end{equation}
Now note that $\forall n\leq d: v^n=\mathrm{Re}\circ e^n$ and $v^{d+n}=\mathrm{Im}\circ e^n$ such that
\begin{equation}
\forall u\in V:v^{d+n}(iu)=(\mathrm{Im}\circ e^n)(iu)=\mathrm{Im}(ie^nu)=\mathrm{Re}(e^nu)=v^{n}(u)
\end{equation}
and hence
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{tr}_\mathbb{R}(A)=2\sum_{n=1}^{n}v^{n}(Ae_n)=2\mathrm{Re}(\mathrm{tr}_\mathbb{C}(A)).
\end{equation}

Comment: Yes, that's right.